# Which is the principal clause here?

Tags: grammar, clauses, comparative-constructions

We know the expression, **"The more . . . the more"** expresses that the two things vary together. A comma separates the two clauses :

> *"The more you have, the more you want".*

Each part is syntactically so alike.

Which is the principal clause in the above sentence?
Which type of subordinate clause does this sentence have?

Comment: Have you done any research on this, or does your grammar book explain which clause is which?

Comment: @BillJ, this question has come to my mind. I am confused about which clause is which in that sentence. But is this your answer to my question?

Comment: I do have an answer for you, but first I'd like to know why such an 'obscure' point of grammar is so important to you.

Comment: @BillJ, we use this construction frequently; but its structure isn't clear to me. I don't know whether it's an obscure point to analyse the clauses of a sentence. If you have any answer, please let me know that. Otherwise, all this is of no use to me.

Comment: This is not a basic clause, nothing like it -- it has a special construction. What do you think is the main clause? You must have some idea.

Comment: And when you get an answer from someone, you either challenge it or try to compare it to the out-of-date grammar that you follow. Note that you can't learn the entire grammar of English on ELL or ELU (or EF). You must get some first-rate modern grammar books, which will help you.

Comment: @BillJ, I do respect you; but it's very strange when you underestimate someone when you cannot give any precise answer. I do follow modern grammar books. I am an M.A. in English, also the Headmaster of a government school. I have a teaching experience of more than 21 years. English is my passion. I use this platform to discuss various matters with the natives. But your reaction is so unexpected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107801/discussion-between-sandip-kumar-mandal-and-billj).

Comment: There, you have your answer, though you are the first person I have ever known who has asked for the syntax of a correlative comparative construction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] *The more you have, the more you want.*

The second one, "the more you want" is the head clause. The first clause is a subordinate one functioning as an adjunct.

We know this because if we convert the sentence to a closed interrogative, it’s on the second clause that subject-auxiliary inversion is performed, meaning that it must be the head clause.

> [2] *Won’t you want more, the more you have?*